# Can't get $filter to work with open types in WCF Data Service

Tags: wcf, odata

I'm building a data service in WCF and I'm using a combination of reflection and open types as some of the data elements need to be created on-the-fly.  Most everything is working well, but I can't get filters to work with the open type values.

The error I get is:

```
  <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
  <innererror>
    <message>The method or operation is not implemented.</message>
    <type>System.NotImplementedException</type>
    <stacktrace>   at lambda_method(Closure , GeographyProvider )&#xD;
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace>
  </innererror>
```

I'm using an expression visitor to rewrite the LINQ expressions and it is successfully pulling the value for the open type.  At this point, I'm not sure what method or operation I need to implement is.  The expression tree looks like this after the expression visitor has done it's work:

```
Alteryx.Web.API.DatasetProvider+<GetDatasets>d__0.Where(element => 
(element.Variant == "AGSSTD_701000")).SelectMany(element => 
    ConvertChecked(element.Geographies)).Where(element => 
        (element.Key == "County")).SelectMany(element => 
            ConvertChecked(element.Geographies)).Where(element => 
                (element.Key == "36")).SelectMany(element => 
                    ConvertChecked(element.Geographies)).Where(it => 
                        Convert(((Invoke((o, name) => GetOpenValue(o, name), it, "POPCY") >= Convert(100000)) == True)))}
```

I've put a break point in the GetOpenValue method and it is getting called and returning the correct value.  Any thoughts on where I need to go from here?

---

Based on Vitek's suggestions, I added checks for Convert and the comparison methods to my expression visitor, but they aren't found.  Here is what my visitor code looks like:

```
    static readonly MethodInfo GetValueOpenPropertyMethodInfo =
        typeof(OpenTypeMethods)
        .GetMethod(
            "GetValue",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(string) },
            null
        );

    static readonly MethodInfo OpenConvertMethodInfo =
        typeof(OpenTypeMethods)
        .GetMethod(
            "Convert",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(ResourceType) },
            null
        );

    static readonly MethodInfo GreaterThanOrEqualMethodInfo =
        typeof(OpenTypeMethods)
        .GetMethod(
            "GreaterThanOrEqual",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) },
            null
        );

    static readonly MethodInfo EqualMethodInfo =
        typeof(OpenTypeMethods)
        .GetMethod(
            "Equal",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) },
            null
        );

        static readonly Expression<Func<object, string, object>> GetValueOpenReplacement =
        (o, name) => GetOpenValue(o, name);


    static object GetOpenValue(object o, string name)
    {
        return (o as OpenDataProvider).GetValue(name);
    }

        static readonly Expression<Func<object, object, object>> GetGreaterThanOrEqualReplacement =
        (left, right) => GetOpenGreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);


    static object GetOpenGreaterThanOrEqual(object left, object right)
    {
        string s = left.ToString();
        return true;
    }

        static readonly Expression<Func<object, object, object>> GetEqualReplacement =
        (left, right) => GetOpenEqual(left, right);


    static object GetOpenEqual(object left, object right)
    {
        string s = left.ToString();
        return true;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(
        MethodCallExpression node
    )
    {
        if (node.Method == GetValueOpenPropertyMethodInfo)
        {
            // Arguments[0] - the resource to get property from 
            // Arguments[1] - the ResourceProperty to get 
            // Invoke the replacement expression, passing the 
            // appropriate parameters. 

            if (node.Arguments[0].Type.BaseType == typeof(OpenDataProvider))
            {
                OpenDataProvider.RequestValue(((ConstantExpression)node.Arguments[1]).Value.ToString());
            }

            return Expression.Invoke(
               Expression.Quote(GetValueOpenReplacement),
               node.Arguments[0],
               node.Arguments[1]
            );
        }
        else if (node.Method == OpenConvertMethodInfo)
        {
            // Arguments[0] – the resource 
            // Arguments[1] – the ResourceType 
            // no need to do anything, so just 
            // return the argument 
            return this.Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
        }
        else if (node.Method == GreaterThanOrEqualMethodInfo)
        {
            // Invoke the replacement expression, passing the 
            // appropriate parameters. 

            return Expression.Invoke(
               Expression.Quote(GetGreaterThanOrEqualReplacement),
               node.Arguments[0],
               node.Arguments[1]
            );
        }
        else if (node.Method == EqualMethodInfo)
        {
            // Invoke the replacement expression, passing the 
            // appropriate parameters. 

            return Expression.Invoke(
               Expression.Quote(GetEqualReplacement),
               node.Arguments[0],
               node.Arguments[1]
            );
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
```

I've put breakpoints in all of the if blocks in the VisitMethodCall method, but only the GetValueOpenProperty block is ever called.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to stop in the debugger on exception and catch that exception in the debugger? Maybe it will show you more. From the above I don't see anything wrong (assuming your GetOpenValue implementation works as expected and you really replaced all the calls to OpenTypeMethods.GetValue in your visitor)

Comment: Actually - one idea - the convert or comparison operators might also be expressed as calls to OpenTypeMethods, did you make sure that you don't leave those in the tree?

Comment: Hi, Vitek.  Thanks for the responses.  I have tried using the debugger, but the exception doesn't stop execution even though I've asked to break when exceptions are thrown.  I've tried replacing the Convert and GreaterThanOrEqual methods on the OpenTypeMethods but neither ever seems to get called.  Perhaps I've defined them wrong.  I'll give it another try and post my ExpressionVisitor code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Added more details above - thanks!

Comment: I don't know the failure yet, just one note on the code style above: Why are you using the Invoke and funcs - that seems way too complicated. Wouldn't a simple Expression.Call suffice? (Although it should not change the functionality).

Comment: I'm extremely new to the whole expression visitor thing, and I was just following Alex's excellent sample:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/02/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-9-un-typed.aspx.  I haven't been able to find any samples that explicitly show using the OpenTypeMethods though, so if you know of any, I would love to see them.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: More info:  I've tracked the exception to a call to OpenTypeMethods.GreaterThanOrEqual, but as you can see I am looking for that in ExpressionVisitor.VistMethodCall and it's not found.  So, where should I be looking to do that replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Vitek kindly provided the answer to this here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/bfb62cf5-48cc-4435-ae9a-76e4a13d762a

To summarize, the ExpressionVisitor needs to overide the OpenTypeMethods in the VisitBinary method.

Thanks for the help, Vitek!